# Handle user concurrency with Shiny Server, keeping variables separate

Tags: r, global-variables, shiny, shiny-server

Hello,

We have a Shiny app running on the free edition of Shiny Server. When we tested it we realized that input changes made by one user affected the session of another user. I understand that there is only one R process running per app, but it seems like there should be a way to keep variables separated for individual user sessions.

I created a more minimal example below. Notice we have sliders with some interdependencies built in - changing one slider can affect the others. The way this is done is by keeping track of 'old' and 'new' values and modifying the other slider by some proportion of the difference - `sliderB` is modified by a fraction of any change to `sliderA`, for example.

I'm eyeing suspiciously the use of `<<-` and the global variables, but I couldn't figure out another way to get this to work. One idea I had was somehow storing variables on the user side via Javascript, but that is thinking pretty far outside of my usual box and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Note that we expect the total number of users to be relatively low, perhaps at most ~100 when the site launches and usually much less than that.

### global.R

```r
a_new <- 10
b_new <- 10
c_new <- 10

a_old <- a_new
b_old <- b_new
```

### server.R

```r
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  vals <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(a = input$sliderA,
                     b = input$sliderB,
                     c = input$sliderC)
  })

  observe({
    a_new <- input$sliderA
    print(paste("a_new:", a_new, "a_old:", a_old))
    b_new <- isolate(input$sliderB) + .5 * (a_new - a_old)
    updateSliderInput(session, "sliderB", value = b_new)
    a_old <<- a_new
  })

  observe({
    b_new <- input$sliderB
    print(paste("b_new:", b_new, "b_old:", b_old))
    c_new <- isolate(input$sliderC) + .5 * (b_new - b_old)
    updateSliderInput(session, "sliderC", value = c_new)
    b_old <<- b_new
  })

  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    data.frame(vals())
  })

})
```

### ui.R

```r
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("sliderA",
                  "A:",
                  min = -50,
                  max = 50,
                  value = a_new),
      sliderInput("sliderB",
                  "B:",
                  min = -50,
                  max = 50,
                  value = b_new),
      sliderInput("sliderC",
                  "C:",
                  min = -50,
                  max = 50,
                  value = c_new)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
))
```

Code is also available here: https://github.com/brianstamper/ShinyApps/tree/master/reactive

Comment: I don't have a testing environment, but how about using `reactiveValues` instead of manipulating global variables?  I thought if you define a `reactiveValues` object within the server function, this may not affect other users.  I may be wrong.

Comment: You should only use `observe` statements to do light operations, as suggested previously use `reactive` expressions to play with `session` variables.

Comment: I tried these ideas out, but no matter how I did it the result was it didn't work anymore, in that sliderA no longer caused changes in sliderB, etc. I will have to look more into the idea of `session` variables, right now I only have that in there from following documentation on `updateSliderInput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all that was really needed was to change where I was declaring the variables.

According to the [Scoping rules for Shiny apps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html),

> The function that you pass to shinyServer() is called once for each session. [...] Everything within this function is instantiated separately for each session.

So all I had to do was put the declaration of `a_old` and `b_old` into the server function and remove them from global.R:

### server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  a_old <- a_new
  b_old <- b_new

  [...]
```

The concurrency problem really had nothing to do with using `reactiveValues` or `observeEvent`, however I do appreciate learning about those because it does get me away from having to use `<<-` for assignment, which was still needed even after moving the variable declarations inside the server function. But the important part here is understanding which variables are shared across all user sessions and which are instantiated separately, and that depends only on where the variables are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example where all the values and changes will be unique per session. Note that I wrapped your `old` variables in the `reactiveValues()`. I also changed to `observeEvent` as I thought its more appropriate in your case. Please note when changing the `sliderA` will cause change in `sliderB` therefore `sliderC` will update also. let me know if you have any questions

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

a_new <- 10
b_new <- 10
c_new <- 10

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("sliderA","A:",min = -50,max = 50,value = a_new),
      sliderInput("sliderB","B:",min = -50, max = 50,value = b_new),
      sliderInput("sliderC","C:",min = -50,max = 50,value = c_new)),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  old <- reactiveValues()

  old$a <- 10
  old$b <- 10
  old$c <- 10

  vals <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(a = input$sliderA,b = input$sliderB,c = input$sliderC)
  })

  observeEvent(input$sliderA,{
    a_new <- input$sliderA
    b_new <- input$sliderB + (.5 * (a_new - old$a))
    updateSliderInput(session, "sliderB", value = b_new)
    old$a <- a_new
  })

  observeEvent(input$sliderB,{
    b_new <- input$sliderB
    c_new <- input$sliderC + (.5 * (b_new - old$b))
    updateSliderInput(session, "sliderC", value = c_new)
    old$b <- b_new
  })

  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    data.frame(vals())
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Although this is useful information, it overlooks the real reason that this solves the concurrency issue - you moved the variable declarations into the server function, and that was all that was really required. I do appreciate this example though, I am making use of it, so thank you for that.

Comment: @BrianStamper http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work